# Authenticating referer site using HTTP_REFERER and IP address

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I have a web service (which returns data) which is accessible only to a few "whitelisted" remote servers. So when a remote server sends a  request to my server, I would check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` field for the whitelisted domain name and the corresponding IP address (which was known to my web-service through a global array). Can this method of whitelisting requests be bypassed?
I know it is easy to implement referer spoofing....but do keep in mind that I am checking both the referer and the corresponding IP address both of which are known to my app with certainty.

If this is NOT a safe thing to do, does anyone have an alternate method of allowing only "whitelisted" domains to access a given web service?

Comment: Just for clarity: You are comparing the remote ip of the requesting client to the ip of the referring host?

Comment: You are checking the IP of *what*? What you get is the *referer* HTTP header, which only has the domain name in it and is easily spoofed, and you know the IP address of the visiting client. They're not the same thing.

Comment: I think I confused the reader. The "client" is actually a remote server which has a domain name associated with it and an IP address as well. And my webpage is truly a web-service which returns data to the caller.....I should have been more clear :) I have edited my question above to incorporate this.

Comment: See [Can I trust the source IP of an HTTP request?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14505/can-i-trust-the-source-ip-of-an-http-request).

Comment: So if the remote server is making a request, I suspect that happens via an automated tool which sends an HTTP request, not by somebody clicking on a link in a browser. Then I'm not sure why the referer header would be set at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I'm not sure why an HTTP Referer header would be set in the first place in your scenario, but let's assume it is and its domain corresponds to the IP of the client. The Referer header is an arbitrary value sent by the client, it's trivially spoofed. The client's IP OTOH is not spoofable (excluding elaborate network level attacks which require the attacker to basically already have compromised one side or the other). What you're asking is whether it makes sense to use an insecure, meaningless value to confirm a value which is already as secure as you can get. And the answer is No. Just stick to the IP filter, that's already good enough.

If you want to strengthen authentication further, use a proper authentication scheme in which you share a secret with your clients (username/password, API token, Oauth or similar).

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe checking the `Referer` HTTP header in addition to the originating IP address yields *any* security benefits at all. Having said this, IP-based auth itself isn't the [safest practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4533). If you really want to protect your API, better look into SSL and some form of [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).